# I'm getting the warning: HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, etc... (Help!)

Tags: hosting, html

I'm building a [webpage](http://www.studyatbest.com/) and I'm getting the following warning (and the page loads but when I change of section it never loads and displays the warning).

The warning:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control:
>   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate,
>   post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma:
>   no-cache Content-Type: text/html
>   Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Date: Wed, 10
>   Mar 2010 12:04:11 GMT Content-Length:
>   4022

I think it didn't happen in my computer at home. The problem seems to happen just few times (apparently random). I'm using cookies and sessions (php) in this web page.

This is getting very strange, I just came back to my house and the problem disappeared (it was because in the another computer I was using Vista?).

Is this a problem with the webpage or the server?

Comment: What you're seeing is the HTTP response header. Normally, web browsers never display this to the end-user.

Comment: If it happens randomly, it's possible that the web server is re-echoing the HTTP response header in the response body. This, too, should normally never happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems everything normal here.

So, Do you have proxy in that environment? In very rare case, some proxy could cause that issue.